# ADT - errors after cleaning project

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I don't know why I cleaned the project, but I did, and now one of my activities is reporting 50 errors, like:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    // activity_settings cannot be resolved or is not a field

    CheckBox check_sound = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.settings_sound);
    // settings_sound cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

And so on. This was working fine before I cleaned the project and nothing has been deleted. Only one activity has errors, no other errors reported in any other file. Tried restarting, Build automatically is enabled, Project>Build and Project>Build All are greyed out.
What's going on?

Comment: Some time automatically generated R.java file will be deleted because of some reasons But as you said after cleaning project it will build and automatically generate R.java file . In R.java file all fields Ids are generated when we create any control in layout (like checkbox,textview,edittext). When R.java file not found any resoure ID then it will give you error like -- activity cannot resolved . So please check your field settings_sound and activity-setting, Is it proper or present or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. For some reason, the first import in the problematic activity was `import android.R`. I don't know how/why it got there. I ran Lint and went through every one of the entries/errors/warnings until I deleted `import android.R` out of desperation. Suddenly everything started working properly again.

Of course when I Googled this solution, I found several answers but for some reason I could not find them before I found the answer myself.

I swear no single programming problem in any of my apps was even close to problems I had dealing with Eclipse/ADT. From a simple SDK update, to reinstallation, to nonsense like this,

Answer (score 1):

Your R.java is missing probably in the gen folder. Right-click on the Project root --> Android Tools --> Fix Project Properties
or even deleting the gen folder and then again cleaning the project will regenerate the R.java file again.

try this too : http://blog.burnayev.com/2009/11/android-developer-tip-regenerating.html
hope this helps.

Comment: No effect. Nothing happens.

Comment: This is the problem of IDE its kind of frustrating but if you repeat this process of deleting the gen folder and try fix the properties again will surely sort the problem or else we have a last resort of copying some other R.java file into it and manually giving the Ids. I know its kinda weird trick and manual work but it will solve the problem for sure.

Comment: Tried that twice, no effect, same thing happens. I don't know what you mean by copying some R.java file and manually giving the ids. I've been programming in Android for a year now, I have no idea what a R.java file is, I never had to deal with it thankfully.

Comment: I know but sometime when IDE behave abnormally need to try these weird tricks. Manually giving the ids is not a proper solution but yes it worked for me as it somehow generates the new R file or the same works. R.java file have all the resources IDs provided to resources(drawbles, layouts, styles etc) either by Programmer, or generated through sdk.

Comment: I don't understand what I need to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57808/discussion-between-moso-and-timsim).

Answer (score 0):

This happens a lot, at least for me. Eclipse is kinda frustrating at times.

This could be something as simple as a typo error in a layout file or a string file and it crops up after a project clean.

Unfortunately eclipse doesn't help and throws only an APT error rather than just showing where the error is. Rest of the times it behaves well by showing errors.

May be you could double check all your layout files and string files thoroughly. One way could be trying to see a graphic layout of your layout files, if all is well, a graphic preview is shown.

Comment: You could check Mobile's comments too. If the link markers are cropping for no reason, removing them might help.